# How to disable Rails sessions for web crawlers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, web-crawler

It used to be that a line like this in the application controller would disable sessions entirely for a request:

```
session :off, :if => Proc.new {|req| req.user_agent =~ BOT_REGEX}
```

With Rails 3.x, this is either deprecated or no longer works. I realize that the new concept is that sessions are lazy loaded, but the execution flow through the app uses/checks sessions even if it's a web bot.

So is there some new mechanism that could be used to disable sessions on a per-request basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a built-in way to do this in Rails 3, but you can monkey patch `SessionHash` to get a similar result:

```
class ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore::SessionHash
  private
    def load_for_write!
      load! unless loaded? || (@env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ BOT_REGEX)
    end
end
```

This will prevent the session store object from being created. You will still be able to assign into the `session` hash, and even access that same session data later in the same request.

Comment: Huh - that's really interesting. How do you know this? I.e., how could I verify this for myself? I guess the source code for the SessionHash.load_for_write! method?

Comment: You can manually test by setting your user agent to something that will be detected as a bot (e.g. [in chrome](http://browserfame.com/314/change-user-agent-chrome-browser)), deleting any existing session cookies you may have, and browsing your site. Each action Rails logs should have the line "No session found" - or you can watch your sessions table if you are using the ActiveRecord SessionStore and verify that no new session records are being added to the database.

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm wondering is, how did you come up with that solution? How do you know you can do that kind of code replacement? And finally, where's the best place to place that code, to work in the Rails boot up sequence?

Comment: I examined the source of `SessionHash` to get a general idea of what it was doing, then placed a breakpoint in `load!` and made a few requests to get a sense of the typical call path. After verifying that Rails' lazy session creation does indeed rely on `load_for_write!` to create the session, I then tested by replacing `load_for_write!` with an implementation that never called `load!` (the original body of `load_for_write!` is `load! unless loaded?`). The code I posted just [re-opens the class](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2007/01/17/reopening-ruby-classes-2/) to change the behavior.

Comment: You can add this code to a file with the path `config/initializers/action_dispatch_mods.rb` and it will automatically be applied during the Rails startup process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming @jordoh's answer works for the default rails cookie_store, but didn't work for me using active_record_store to store my sessions in the database.

If you're using the active_record_store and want to stop sessions being created for bots this works:

```
# Save this file as config/initializers/session_store_ext.rb 
# and don't forget to define BOT_REGEX

class ActiveRecord::SessionStore
  _set_session = instance_method :set_session

  define_method :set_session  do | env, sid, session_data, options |
    unless env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ BOT_REGEX
      _set_session.bind(self).call env, sid, session_data, options
    end

    sid
  end

  private :set_session
end
```

I've written a blog post detailing this - [Conditionally Disabling Database Sessions in Ruby on Rails 3](http://bugmuncher.com/2015/07/13/conditionally-disabling-database-sessions-rails-3.html)