# Stop bot from using sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, bots

I am developing a site and using Heroku for my hosting.  I am on the their dev plan which allows me to use their free database but only up to 10,000 rows.  After not touching the site for two days I was shocked to see an email alert from Heroku saying that I had reached 7,400 rows in my db.  After some research I realized search bots were creating sessions.  Is there a way to stop this?  I have tried the solution in this post but it does not seem to work:

[How to disable Rails sessions for web crawlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987797/how-to-disable-rails-sessions-for-web-crawlers)

I am using rails 3.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in this question ( [Setting session timeout in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3)), you can implement auto expiry of your session and delete the database rows when a session has expired. If you keep session expiry time low and keep dropping database rows, I guess you won't hit your Heroku limit.

Comment: There has got to be a better answer than this, any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you storing sessions in your DB? I would suggest you look for server/site settings that is doing it and disable it. There is no point in storing sessions in DB in most cases and **definitely** not on development site.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but there were reasons I chose db session store.  Can you still provide me an answer to my question?

Comment: If the solution that you mentioned in your post (link to earlier post) does not work, then you should check the user agent strings passed by the bots in your case and adjust the regex accordingly. And look at "Kulbir Saini" option too.

Comment: Downvoted because Sessions in DB is the safer way of handling security. See Rails guides about Session Storage: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage

Comment: @AminAriana I think that you did NOT read the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-guidelines completely. It does NOT suggest storing sessions in DB, but storing sensitive information in DB instead of session.